# Make a trait require an unspecified Enumeration as part of its interface

Tags: scala, enumeration, traits

How can I define a trait which defines that my case class should contain an `Enumeration` of some kind, when I don't want it locked to one specific `Enumeration`? See the explanation for more details:

---

I have some data that has three integer fields per entry, and each integer increases the specificity of the data.

The first field is the overall type of the data, like what industry is it from (e.g. baking), the second field is what kind of product it is (e.g. cake), and the third field is the type of product (e.g. strawberry pie).

I'm trying to map this data like so:

1. Each industry has its own case class

   ```
   case class BakingProduct(...)
   ```
2. Each case class has an `Enumeration` in it.

   ```
   case object BakingType extends Enumeration { type Product = Value, ... }
   case class BakingProduct(primary: BakingType.Product, ...)
   ```
3. Each case class also holds an `Int` for the final field (it's not important enough for me to make an `Enumeration` for it)

   ```
   case class BakingProduct(primary: BakingType.Product, secondary: Int)
   ```

To me this strikes a good balance between readability and writability, as opposed to creating case classes for every single combination, but my issue is that I want to create a trait that can encompass these `Product` classes; something like this:

```
trait ProductType { 
    val primary: Enumeration, 
    val secondary: Int 
}
```

such that

```
case class BakingProduct(primary: BakingType.Product, secondary: Int) extends ProductType
```

is valid, but without locking `primary` to a specific type of `Enumeration`, such that I can make an `Enumeration` for each specific `ProductType` I want to use.

Should I try to make a parent `Enumeration` to encompass those other `Enumeration`s (and if so, how? I haven't been able to figure that out)? I would also like to avoid making the trait generic if possible, so I don't have to give type parameters whenever I'm dealing with one. But if there's a nice way to do it with generics then that would be welcome as well, along with other suggestions :)